# Selenium: How to click individual item from 'find_elements' list

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm having a problem where I have a list of elements:

### Find Elements:

```
arialabel = (list([my_elem.get_attribute("aria-label") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content>div[aria-label]")))]))
```

### Output

`['solid', 'massive; solid', 'hazy, indistinct', 'akimbo', 'monolithic', 'hands on hips, elbows bent', 'inimical', 'Nebulous', 'to explode', 'hostile; harmful', 'state of matter', 'fulminate']`

And I know the locations of each of the corresponding items in the list since this is a list of mixed terms and definitions, so when I try to click on an element using this:

```
    for _ in sort_order:

        pos1sort = sort_order[tempVar2]
        sortedList = [i for i in range(len(sort_order)) if sort_order[i] == pos1sort]
        arialabel.click([sortedList[0]])
        arialabel.click([sortedList[1]])
        print(sortedList)
        tempVar2+=1
```

I of course get an error saying
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

These are the corresponding positions of the items in the list.

```
[1, 4]
[2, 9]
[3, 7]
[1, 4]
[0, 5]
[6, 8]
[3, 7]
[6, 8]
[2, 9]
[10, 11]
[10, 11]
```

sorry for the long question, but I was wondering how I would use the click() function in selenium in order to click a specific item in a list, similar to how I attempted to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Found It Out

container was just another variable assigned to a find elements function

```
container = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('MatchModeQuestionGridTile-content')
```

```
for _ in sort_order:
        sorted1 = int(sortedList[0])
        sorted2 = int(sortedList[1])
        container[sorted1].click()
        container[sorted2].click()
```